# Example of metric space s.t. $A$ intersects $B$ is an empty set.

Tags: general-topology

Give an example of metric space $(X,d)$ and subsets $A$ and $B$ of $X$ such that $A$ intersects $B$ equals an empty set but $d(A,B)=0$.

I know that for $A$ and $B$ to be an intersection they have to have sets that are not contained in one another. The distance of $A$ and $B$ equal zero when $A$ and $B$ equal each other. Could I use an example of coordinates like $A=(1,4]$ and $B=(4,6)$? $A$ and $B$ would give us an empty set but I just not sure what I could use to show the distance is zero.

Comment: Your example is fine. $d(A,B) = \inf_{x\in A,y\in B} d(x,y)$. Take the sequence $(4+\frac{1}{n})$ in $B$, $4\in A$. The distance between those points is an upper bound for $d(A,B)$.

Comment: So saying (4+1/n) in B and 4 exists in A than the distance between A and B is zero because it is an upper bound?

Comment: Yes, $d(A,B) \leq d(4, 4+1/n) \rightarrow 0$

Answer (score 1):

What definition of distance between sets are you using? If it is the infimum of the distances between its points, then a possibility would be to consider $X=\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric and the sets $\lbrace \frac{1}{n}\,|\,n\in\mathbb{N} \rbrace$ and $\lbrace-\frac{1}{n}\,|\,n\in\mathbb{N}\rbrace$.